# play mp3 blob using <audio controls> on flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

I did a json request to get a response in the form of a blob file with content-type audio/mpeg.

The response in the form of a blob is then sent to jinja html with a rendering template like the following

```
audio = tts.get_audio()
if audio:
    # return audio #<-- using this successfully plays the audio, but only displays the player. I want to display the player inside tts.html page 
    return render_template('tts.html', audio=audio)
```

on the tts.html

```
{% if audio %}
  <audio controls>
    <source src="{{ audio }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
  {% endif %}
```

with the above code I get an error like this

```
"GET /b'/xff/xf3/xc8/xc4/x00/x00/x00/x03H/x00/x00/x00/x00LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUULAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU//x02%60A/xcbL/xb3/xe63/x99/xca%5E/xb4/xb46/xb4!i/xb8dA/x98/x0b/x81/x01%60a/xab/xf7m/xeaD/xc4PvA/xa34/xac/xd6T+xPN/x01/x02/x02/x06/xaf/xd0/x98a/x04/x01/x86-/x93/x188/xc5/x02c/x88f/x01/x06%60/xc0/x96m/x00jn/xa0/x05/xa80@/x130/x1a4/xcf/xaf7./xcd/xa9/xf0/xb8CZ/xbc1/xb9/x88Dj/x91/x04/x114/xf3O?3\xd3\x0cF\xa0\xfa\xfb%3C\xadDh\r\xf4ctx\x80\xf9\xc3\xaet\xd9\x92*%3E}\xcf+\xb3\x02@\xd9B8M\x81O\x00\xa5\xcc\xe9\x11PF\xa5y\xa7&\x9a\xc6\x001\x88\x04\xab\x10\x16\x97`\x81F\x95\x19\x99\x0e\x9e\xc6\x18P(b~\x98\xff\xf3\xc8\xc4\xb3y\xb4\x15\x10\x01X\xd0\x00\xb2 HTTP/1.1" 404
```

how can I resolve the error?